# How to convert an NSTimeInterval into an date with time?

Tags: iphone, date

I have an NSTimeInterval value, or more precisely an NSTimeInterval "since reference date". I think that's a value in seconds from 1970 or something like so. Pretty standard in most programming languages, I think.

So now I have that ugly value which the user doesn't understand, and I'd like to display a date + time. Is there a useful method or function that would do that, maybe by specifying formats or a locale as well? Maybe the iphone also has built-in support for this kind of stuff so that the date+time is displayed automatically like the user likes it in his/her settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create an `NSDate` with [+[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can then get the date's `-descriptionWithLocale:` or use the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) from the iPhone library to find out more options for displaying the date.